# ajax post to php dynamically

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have a signup form which uses

```js
function user_reg(user_name,user_email,user_pswd)
{
 var serverpath=window.location; 
 alert(serverpath);
  var dataString = 'name='+ user_name + '&email=' + user_email + '&pswd=' + user_pswd + '&page=user_reg';
  $.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url:  "/pages/login.php",
   data: dataString,
   cache: false,
   success: function(response)
   {
    var response_brought = response.indexOf('registered_successfully=yes');
    if (response_brought != -1) 
    {
     $('#signup_thanks').openModal();
    // window.location.replace(response);
    } 
   }
  });
}
```

this function is in signup.js file which is is in ./js folder. This script file is needed in both index.php which is in the root and in signup.php file which is in ./pages folder. And the above code posts the data to login.php which is a;sp in ./pages folder. when I include signup.js in index.php the above code works but when I add it in signup.php it won't post to ./pages/login.php it post to ./pages/pages/login.php which don't exist. So how can I do this. Please help.
Thankyou

Comment: `url:  "/pages/login.php",` - you should change your relative path, consider removing the first `/` or adding a `.` prior to it.

Comment: u will have to pass url as variable to user_reg function. Or determine  url with switch based on current filename.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this and see
url:  "../pages/login.php",